# Save snapshot from HTML5 webcam using PHP

Tags: php, html, webcam

I am planning on setting up a (family friendly) webcam hosting service using HTML5 and PHP. To  start with, I need to set up the webpage which takes the photo.

I am looking for a system which uses HTML5 to connect to the webcam then can automatically take a photo every minute. I will then need it to upload the photo and send data to a MySQL database using PHP.

Does anyone know where I could be able to find a way to do this?

If there is no way of doing this, does anyone know any more secure alternatives which can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible with html5 API's like navigator.getUserMedia and navigator.mozGetUserMedia en it should also be possible to generate a data (base64_encoded) string based on a canvas image that you can send by AJAX or FILE API's to a PHP script

html5rocks has good examples for it.

Comment: Thanks! html5rocks looks very useful.

Comment: Here you can get a working sample of capturing image from webcam using html5:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463874/Webcam-and-Annotation-With-HTML5